# How to run pipeline only on changes to any markdown file in the repo?

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I want this job to run if any markdown file in the entire repository has been modified. I am using the

`only: changes:` tags, but how to specify all markdown files in all directories and subdirectories?

Currently I have `/**/*.md` but this only returns markdown files that are one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.md"
```

Note that the pattern is wrapped in double quotes, as [documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges) in the GitLab site.